# jinja2 first x items in for ... if loop

Tags: python, loops, flask, jinja2

I have the following loop in my jinja2 template

```
{% for item in list if item.author == 'bob' %}
```

I am trying to get the first 5 items who have bob as an author.

I tried doing

```
{% for item in list if item.author == 'bob' and loop.index <= 5 %}
```

but it returned an undefined error.

How to make it work?

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing you generally want to do in your python code, not the template.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

EDIT:

you can simply nest the expressions?, i.e.

```
{% for item in list if item.author == 'bob' %}
    {% if loop.index <= 5 %}
       do something
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This would get the first 5 items of the array, not the ones with author bob.. If i have an array with 10 items and bob wrote the last 5, this will not return anything

Comment: i would agree with Wooble, this sort of logic should probably be sorted before you get to the template, maybe make the list a dict of lists with the authors being the keys?

Comment: what about nested loops? how do access the `loop` variable from a parent loop

Answer (score 7):

to skip the first x elements you can

```
{% for category in categories[x:] %}
```

with all the expressions you can use for the regular lists

Answer (score 5):

You can also use

```
{% for item in list[0:6] %}
```